# Checking DIV elements display style

Tags: javascript, css, dom-node

I have a div container `id="cMsgArea"` that is used to host multiple divs that are dynamically added via AJAX.   I need to control the number of child divs that are visible at any given time.

```js
var theDIV = document.getElementById('cMsgArea');
console.log('1)' + theDIV.innerHTML );
var divNode = theDIV.firstChild;
console.log('divNode:' + divNode.innerHTML);
console.log("divNodeDisplay:" + divNode.style.display);
console.log("divNodeStyle:" + divNode.style );
while (divNode.style.display !== "block") {
    divNode = divNode.nextSibling;
}
return divNode;
```

**console results:**

```
1)<div style="float:left; clear:left;">[<i>2014.07.05 13:21:09</i>]DreamGuru:(1)(1)</div><div style="float:left; clear:left;">[<i>2014.07.05 13:21:09</i>]DreamGuru:(2)(1)</div><div style="float:left; clear:left;">[<i>2014.07.05 13:21:14</i>]DreamGuru:(1)(12)</div><div style="float:left; clear:left;">[<i>2014.07.05 13:21:14</i>]DreamGuru:(2)(12)</div> si5.js:140 
divNode:[<i>2014.07.05 13:21:09</i>]DreamGuru:(1)(1) si5.js:142 
divNodeDisplay: si5.js:143 
divNodeStyle:[object CSSStyleDeclaration] si5.js:144 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

**Question**
`divNode` is showing me the correct value for `innerHTML` but `.style.display` is indicating that style is null.  How do I get the 'style.display' value?

**Update**
Patrick Evans was correct, I was looking at the wrong end of the problem.   That said, it is resolved, but I also want to note that I also had to make a change to the code that was adding divs to the container to explicitly add that the style include `display:block`.

Comment: no that error is indicating that you are trying to access the property `style` on a null object, this means `divNode` is null, meaning that at some point you reached the end of the siblings. you need a different condition in the while: eg `while( divNode!==null )` and do the style check in the while block

Comment: divNode is not null.  The console is showing the innerHTML values (si5.js:142).  I had an alert in the while loop that correctly went through 4 iterations.  Error message is indicating that 'style' is null.

Comment: Yes but you are doing the innerHTML logs on the first `divNode` and before you go into the while lopp. And each iteration through the loop you are overwriting `divNode` to be whatever `nextSibling` is. So when it reaches the last sibling `nextSibling` is going to be null because there is no next sibiling, hence then `divNode` will be null in the next iteration, which is when the error is thrown

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer.  I see what you are saying.  I'll try checking that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the style information from here

```
$("#yourID").prop('style')
```

Comment: The question did not mention jQuery.